# How Do I Add a Permanent Text Block on The Checkout Page?

Tags: design

I am trying to save a little money and learn to design a WP site myself.
On my Checkout page, I need my customers to write in personalization information
about their custom order.
I have a customization box that is required, but the details that are needed are displayed in the box and when the customer starts typing, the details disappear!

I would like to have those details permanently displayed above the box. Under the "Additional Information" title would be great.
How can I do this?

I have Woocommerce, Elementor & Astra. I tried 2 checkout plugins that couldn't help.

[image]

Comment: At first glance you could generate some text from the woocommerce_after_order_notes hook, but that's after all the additional fields and not just this one. Or you could add a woocommerce_form_field hook which need to check which field you're generating and then append or edit some text into the HTML it has been given. Or I expect this could be done with your theme too, but I've no idea how to do this from Elementor or Astra.

Comment: Thanks, Rup. I am a little lost though on the "hook" part though. Would you mind sharing in novice terms? :)

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API), although it's probably not beginner friendly either.
They're for PHP code you've written in a plugin or theme to change or extend WordPress behaviour. There are two types of hooks: actions, which give your code an opportunity to do something - e.g. WooCommerce's woocommerce_after_order_notes action is called during the generation of the form after the 'additional information' section, to give you a chance to write more text;

Comment: and filters, where your code is given a chance to change a value - e.g. WooCommerce's woocommerce_form_field filter which passes through the HTML generated for a field and then you can check if it's the additional information field and change the HTML.

Comment: However if you weren't planning to write PHP code then you could probably just override the WooCommerce template instead and edit in the extra text as HTML there. [Here's the WooCommerce documentation on that](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1) I think. Apologies I haven't done this myself before.